# pass variable through render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am making nested form, like it was done in railscasts and have a problem with render.
In my form i have

```
 <% form_for @question, :url => user_questions_path, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "text_input" %>
          <%= f.label :description %>
          <%= f.text_area :description, :cols => "1", :rows => "1", :class => "textarea" %>

          <div id="reg">
           <%= render :partial => "user_form", :f => f %>
          </div>


          ...
<% end %>
```

and in my user_form file I have

```
<% f.fields_for :user do |builder| %>
             <%= builder.label :email %>
             <%= builder.text_field :email, :class => "text_input" %>
             <%= builder.label :password %>
             <%= builder.text_field :password, :class => "text_input" %>
             <%= builder.label :password_confirmation %>
             <%= builder.text_field :password_confirmation, :class => "text_input" %>
             <% builder.fields_for :user_profile, @question.user.user_profile || @question.user.build_user_profile do |u| %>
                 <%= u.label :secondname %>
                 <%= u.text_field :secondname, :class => "text_input" %>
                 <%= u.label :firstname %>
                 <%= u.text_field :firstname, :class => "text_input" %>
             <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have an error in first line of partial

> undefined local variable or method `f' for

what I am doing wrong?(I am using rails 2.3, but in cast rails 2 were used too).
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing `:locals => {...}`. Two more advices: 1) use `[:user, @question]` as resource and you could skip the :url option. 2) Call `fields_for` outside the user partial, that improves modularity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you may need to change

```
<%= render :partial => "user_form", :f => f %>
```

to one of the following:

```
<%= render "user_form", :f => f %>
<%= render :partial => "user_form", :locals => {:f => f} %>
```

Comment: thanks `:partial => "user_form", :locals => {:f => f} %>` helped

Comment: Awesome! The shorter form will work in later versions of Rails -- I wasn't sure what version that was added.